# How to compare times as strings in the format "HH:MM:SS"?

Tags: java, android, time

How to check if the user is on time.

Example:
The program starts at 13:50:00, and ends at 14:50:00.

And if a user logs in, and his time is 14:30:00, he can log in.
If he comes in again at 14:55:00 he can't come in again.

Comment: We need more informations in order to be able to answer you, right now your question is very unclear, please try to riformulate it and maybe add some sample code.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please learn that you’re supposed to search before posting a question here. In this case I am convinced that just a quick search would already have got you some of the way. More guidelines are here: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can parse the given time strings into `LocalTime` and then use `LocalTime#isBefore` and `LocalTime#isAfter` to find the eligibility.

**Demo:**

```
import java.time.LocalTime;

public class Main {
    static final String startTime = "13:50:00";
    static final String endTime = "14:50:00";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Test
        System.out.println(canLogin("13:50:00"));
        System.out.println(canLogin("14:30:00"));
        System.out.println(canLogin("14:55:00"));
        System.out.println(canLogin("14:50:00"));
    }

    static boolean canLogin(String arrivalTime) {
        LocalTime start = LocalTime.parse(startTime);
        LocalTime end = LocalTime.parse(endTime);
        LocalTime arrival = LocalTime.parse(arrivalTime);
        return !arrival.isAfter(end) && !arrival.isBefore(start);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
true
true
false
true
```

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/CHjaFj)

Learn more about the [modern Date-Time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-Date-Time.html)<sup>*</sup> from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

---

<sup>* If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table). Note that Android 8.0 Oreo already provides [support for `java.time`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/time/package-summary).</sup>

Comment: Good answer. If you get string input, you need to parse it as shown in the answer. If you don’t, skip that relatively time-consuming step. Declare for example `static final LocalTime start = LocalTime.of(13, 50); `. And get the current time from `LocalTime arrival = LocalTime.now(ZoneId.systemDefault());`.